# IsFirstRowAsColumnNames and ResultGrid does not exist

Tags: c#, winforms

resultgrid and IsfirstrowAsColumnNames

```
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e, object ResultGrid ) 
{
  using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog()
    { Filter = "Excel workbook|*xls", ValidateNames = true })
  {
    if (dialog.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
    {
      FileStream fileStream = File.Open(dialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fileStream);
      reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames()() = false;
      ds = reader.AsDataSet();
      ResultGrid.DataSource() = ds.Tables[0];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no question

Comment: You can't just invent your own parameters like that for an event.